# Help identifying forum spammers via a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a simple query that I can run against a database to return abnoralities in the time threshold that users post to our forum.  If I have the following database structure:

```
ThreadId | UserId | PostAuthor | PostDate |
1          1000     Spammer      2010-11-14 02:52:50.093
2          1000     Spammer      2010-11-14 02:53:06.893
3          1000     Spammer      2010-11-14 02:53:22.130
4          1000     Spammer      2010-11-14 02:53:37.073
5          2000     RealUser     2010-11-14 02:53:52.383
6          1000     Spammer      2010-11-14 02:54:07.430
```

I would like to set a threshold to say for instance, that if 3 posts, from the same user, fall within a time period of 1 minute, the poster may be spamming the forums.  In turn, I would like to return user 'Spammer' in a query, with the number of posts made within the allotted time.

In the above example, Spammer posted 4 messages within a time period of 1 minute, so the result of the query may look like the following:

```
UserId | PostAuthor | PostCount | DateStart               | DateEnd
1000     Spammer      4           2010-11-14 02:52:50.093   2010-11-14 02:53:37.073
```

Any suggestions in the format of the returned data our welcome.  The format doesn't matter me as much as correctly identifying forum abusers accurately.

Comment: does it have to be 3 consecutive posts without interruption? For example if Spammer posts threads 1 and 2 at 2:52:50 and 2:53:06 , then RealUser posts thread 3 at 2:53:10 and then Spammer posts another thread at 2:53:15, so would that be counted as an abuse? i think it should be and that would simplify things a bit

Comment: No, they may not be consecutive.  As long as the user posts 3 times within 1 minute, regardless of how many posts were in between their posts, it should still recognize the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't have everything you wanted in the output, but it's a start:

(Reword: give me all posts for which 2 or more other posts exist after it, but within one minute)

```
Select 
  Spammer = PostAuthor,
  NumberOfPosts = (Select Count(*) 
                   From Posts As AllPosts 
                   Where AllPosts.UserID = Posts.UserID)
From Posts
Where 2 <= (Select Count(*)
            From Posts As OtherPosts
            Where OtherPosts.UserID = Posts.UserID
              And OtherPosts.PostDate > Posts.PostDate
              And OtherPosts.PostDate < DateAdd(Minute, 1, Posts.PostDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Self join solution:

```
Select T1.UserId, T1.PostAuthor, T1.PostDate, Max(T2.PostDate), Count(*)
from
  Posts T1 INNER JOIN Posts T2 
  ON T1.UserId = T2.UserId and 
     T2.PostDate between T1.PostDate and dateadd(minute, 1, T1.PostDate)
group by T1.UserId, T1.PostAuthor, T1.PostDate
having count(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying my hand at this and came up with this (i guess it gives almost the same result as the one by Stu, albeit the count of posts). This identifies users who have 3 posts within 1 minute (So in case of 5 posts, it repeats the user 3 times)

```
DECLARE @threshold INT;
SET @threshold = 3;

;WITH postCTE as
(
SELECT 
  Userid,
  PostAuthor,
  PostDate,
  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by UserId ORDER BY PostDate ASC)
FROM Posts
)
SELECT 
  p1.UserId, 
  p1.PostAuthor, 
  p1.PostDate AS StartTime, 
  p2.PostDate AS EndTime
FROM postCTE p1
   JOIN postCTE p2 
     ON p1.UserId = p2.UserId 
     AND p1.Rownumber = p2.RowNumber - (@threshold - 1)
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,p1.PostDate,p2.PostDate) <= 1
```

Returns the following result set

```
UserId   PostAuthor  StartTime                EndTime
1000    Spammer    2010-11-14 02:52:50.093  2010-11-14 02:53:22.130
1000    Spammer    2010-11-14 02:53:06.893  2010-11-14 02:53:37.073
1000    Spammer    2010-11-14 02:53:22.130  2010-11-14 02:54:07.430
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sadhir is on the right track.  I have a couple of corrections to the script.  The first correction involves using the DATADIFF units of 'minute'.  Using the minute will not correctly return the four records from the example by George.  I changed the 'minute' to 'seconds'.  I also formatted the output to show the number of posts recorded during the minute by calculating the difference between the rownumbers in the CTE.
While George did not request it I added a parameter to controll the number of days to look back into the table since I did not think anyone would want to do the whole table every time.

```
DECLARE @threshold INT; 
SET @threshold = 3; 
DECLARE @lookbackdays int;
SET @lookbackdays = 2;

;WITH postCTE as 
( 
SELECT  
    Userid, 
    PostAuthor, 
    PostDate, 
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserId,PostDate ASC) 
FROM 
    Post2Forum 
WHERE 
    PostDate > GETDATE() - @lookbackdays
) 
SELECT  
    p1.PostAuthor AS [PostAuthor],  
    p2.RowNumber - p1.RowNumber +1 AS [PostCount],
    p1.UserId,  
    p1.PostDate AS [DateStart],  
    p2.PostDate AS [DateEnd] 
FROM 
    postCTE p1 
INNER JOIN 
    postCTE p2  
    ON p1.UserId = p2.UserId  
    AND p1.Rownumber = p2.RowNumber - (@threshold ) 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(second,p1.PostDate,p2.PostDate) <= 60
```

The result of the query in my testing is:

```
PostAuthor PostCount UserId                   DateStart            DateEnd
Spammer           4   1000 2010-11-14 02:52:50.093  2010-11-14 02:53:37.073
```

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you want, but would serve the purpose more or less...

```
SELECT 
  UserId, 
  PostAuthor, 
  COUNT(*) AS [PostCount],
  YEAR(PostDate), 
  MONTH(PostDate), 
  DAY(PostDate), 
  DATEPART(hh, PostDate), 
  DATEPART(mi, PostDate)
FROM LogTable
GROUP BY 
  UserId, 
  PostAuthor, 
  YEAR(PostDate), 
  MONTH(PostDate), 
  DAY(PostDate), 
  DATEPART(hh, PostDate), 
  DATEPART(mi, PostDate)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
ORDER BY 
  YEAR(PostDate), 
  MONTH(PostDate), 
  DAY(PostDate), 
  DATEPART(hh, PostDate), 
  DATEPART(mi, PostDate)
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This query is simple and works to solve the stated problem.